# Joining array values into string in MySQL multiple insert

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

In a form, multiple Checkbox values to be inserted into database:

My Code:

```
Array: ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 )

$a = $_POST['id']; // data from form
$query = "INSERT INTO abc(`x`,`y`,`z`) VALUES " . implode (",","(NULL,$a,'1')");

mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
```

There seems to be a problem with implode function. How do you concat array using implode?

// Expected output

```
INSERT INTO abc(`x`,`y`,`z`) VALUES (NULL,1,'1'),(NULL,2,'1'),(NULL,3,'1'),(NULL,4,'1'),
```

Column `y` of table abc needs to loop with $a.

Comment: `implode()` function takes `array` as second argument. Can you check again in your code?

Comment: do you want to insert `$a` values into column name `y`?

Comment: yes, i need to enter $a value into column y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a batch multiple insertions, first build the batches first, then implode those batches:

```
$multiple = array_map(function($e) use($dbc) {
    $e = $dbc->real_escape_string($e);
    return "(NULL, $e, '1')";
}, $a);
$query = "INSERT INTO abc(`x`,`y`,`z`) VALUES " . implode (',', $multiple);
mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
```

Sidenotes: Its not `VALUE`, Its `VALUES`. And remember to use the correct quotes on identifiers. Its supposed to be backticks not single quotes.

```
INSERT INTO abc('x','y','z') // NOT OK
INSERT INTO abc(`x`,`y`,`z`) // OK
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ghost, your feed gave me what i wanted. Sorry about the mistakes, i was posting as a reference. I will edit it for others. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4);
$string = '';
foreach($a as $v){
    $string .= "(NULL, $v, 1),";
}
$string = substr($string,0,-1);


$query = "INSERT INTO abc('x','y','z') VALUES $string";
```

Comment: that would give me , VALUE ( 1,2,3,4). I am expecting a full query with, 
VALUE (NULL, 1, 1),(NULL, 2, 1),(NULL, 3, 1),(NULL, 4, 1)

Comment: OK, I got it. Edited my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Here you do implode concate.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO abc('x','y','z') VALUE " . "('" . implode("','", $a) . "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Youre using wrong arguments in implode [implode()](http://php.net/function.implode) and check your insert query you must use `values` instead of `value`

```
$query = "INSERT INTO abc('x','y','z') VALUES (".implode(",",$a).")";
```

Comment: You should post corrections instead of repeating user's code.

Comment: Actually, according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html, you can use VALUE or VALUES

Answer (score 0):

As per your comments in question, This should be your code:

```
foreach($a as $item)
{
 $str[] = "(NULL, '$item', 1)";
}

$query = "INSERT INTO abc(x,y,z) VALUES ".implode(',', $str);
```

So, you were doing two mistakes:

1. VALUE should be VALUES
2. Using implode at wrong place